# Angular New files not creating

Tags: angular

So i typed ng new my_app and a dialog box comes like this.If anyone knows how to fix this problem please tell me about it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFjaW.png)

Answer (score 2):

You typed `mg` instead of `ng`. `mg` is a text-editor.